# How do i get $b$ from ${b\over2-3ab}=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this expression:
$${b\over2-3ab}=2$$

So now i try to get $b$

I started with:

$${2-3a} = {1 \over 2}$$

But how you can see $b$ gets lost, what did i wrong?
Thanks!

My teacher said the right answer would be $b = {4\over 6a+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it, you did two steps:
$$
\frac{b}{2-3ab}=2=\frac{1}{2}
$$
so you inverted both sides
$$
\frac{2-3ab}{b}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
and then you 'tried' to cancel out the factor $b$. But here you made a mistake, since
$$
\frac{2-3ab}{b}=\frac{2}{b}-\frac{3ab}{b}=\frac{2}{b}-3a\mbox{, which does not equal: } 2-3a
$$
You should instead have done what Lucian suggests.

Comment: +1 for showing the OP what went wrong, rather than just demonstrating a different method.

Answer (score 2):

$$b=2(2-3ab)=4-6ab\iff b+6ab=4\iff b(1+6a)=4\iff b=\frac4{1+6a}$$